# Does Google Canary browser support generators of ES6?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, generator, ecmascript-harmony

I need to test/work **generators** that are part of the **ES6** draft. To work on I need a browser(in my case). As Google Canary is strictly for developers, so does it support generators as of now? My OS is Windows 7.

Comment: you might be interested in https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler

Comment: You may also be interested in http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/ to know what's available on the browser you're using (I'm aware it wouldn't have helped you as you have to activate the flag on chrome, I'm putting it here for information purposes only).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, behind a flag. See also the [feature dashboard entry](http://www.chromestatus.com/features/4959347197083648) and [V8 bug](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2355).

Navigate to `chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony` to enable it.

Comment: Can the flag be enabled on google chrome current version too??

Comment: Yes. But be aware that this is an experimental feature at the moment, and so support may be incomplete or buggy. Canary is likely to have a more recent implementation, but I'm not familiar enough with this feature to describe its status in each version except to point you at the dashboard and bug.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for experimenting with generators on a Chromebook and this did the trick!